# What tools are available for inspecting/probing a type in Julia

Tags: types, julia

`typeof(foo)` gives me the type. But suppose I wish to dig deeper.

e.g.

- supertype / tree
- List data members
- Jump to source code definition
- help/doc
- anything else?  Which module it is defined in?

Can I do better than simply throwing `TheTypeName site:http://docs.julialang.org` into Google?

http://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.5/manual/types/ contains some answers: `supertype` and `fieldnames` but it would be nice to have some compact at-a-glance reference.

Comment: `dump` is very informative when needing to get some verbose info.

Answer (score 7):

I just added a recipe to [PlotRecipes](https://github.com/JuliaPlots/PlotRecipes.jl) to visualize a type tree.  I had this in a notebook, and it was easy to copy/paste into a recipe, so why not.  In this example, I'm "plotting" the type tree of the `LearnBase.Learnable` abstract type:

```
using PlotRecipes, Learn
pyplot(size=(800,500))
theme(:dark)
plot(Learnable, method=:tree)
```

[image]

Comment: Could you show how to make the text larger and increase the size ratio of the surrounding boxes to the text?

Comment: I haven't settled on a final API for the graph plots yet, but you can see a bunch of current options (which are in addition to the normal Plots attributes) here: https://github.com/JuliaPlots/PlotRecipes.jl/blob/master/src/graphs.jl#L222-L242.  For text, use `fontsize`, and for fine-tuning the relative shape size, you can pass a tuple to markersize: `ms = (1.5, 0.5)`

Answer (score 3):

For supertype you can call `supertype(FooType)`. For all ancestors, this should work:

```
function supertypes(t::DataType)
    T = [t]
    tsup = supertype(t)
    if t !== tsup
        prepend!(T, supertypes(tsup))
    end
    return T
end
```

For fieldnames of the type, use `fieldnames`.

Source code for functions can be found by using the `edit` function or the `@edit` macro, but I cannot make it work for type definitions.

Help: `? FooType`

Answer (score 3):

Three additions:

- `isimmutable(foo)` to check if an *object* is  immutable
- `isbits(typeof(foo))` to check for the memory layout of the type
- `methodswith(typeof(foo), true)` to get a list of methods that will accept foo as an argument